# how to check an ip address is local

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is code:

```
def isSrsInternal(srcip):
    here i want to write code to check that srcip is local source to thet network  or not
    if srcip is local than it will return true 
    else return false
```

1 Can anyone give me the idea to writing that function

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using the [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address.is_private) module:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address('192.168.0.1')
>>> ip2 = ipaddress.IPv4Address('64.233.160.143') #Google's IP address
>>> ip.is_private
True
>>> ip2.is_private
False
```